# What is the difference between "I crushed the cockroach dead" and "I crushed the cockroach to death"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, phrase-usage, phrase-request, phrase-choice

I remember someone said to me that "the man crushed the box flat", so that is the structure "**to crush + N + adjective**".

And it seems most dictionaries say "**to crush + N + to death**".

My question is that,

Can we say  "**I crushed the cockroach dead**"?

If we can, then

What is the difference between "**I crushed the cockroach dead**" and "**I crushed the cockroach to death**"?

Comment: Just say you crushed the cockroach. That's bound to kill it, so there's no reason to explicitly mention ***death***. But all ways of saying it would mean the same thing.

Comment: In more credible example contexts, it's normally  *She shot him dead*, not *She shot him to death*. BUT it's normally *She rocked the baby to sleep* rather than *She rocked the baby asleep*. The way the "result" condition is expressed very much depends on the specific main verb that *causes* the result.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, maybe, " She shot him dead" means just 1 shot and he is dead instantly and "She shot him to death" means she shot him several times before he was actually dead

Comment: @FumbleFingers - In British news sources you more often see 'shot (someone) dead' where US sources might say 'shot (someone) to death', and in both zones it can be done with one or more than one bullet. I don't think you can beat, stab, kick, etc, someone dead.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: Apparently [a couple of centuries ago](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=stabbed+him+dead%2Cstabbed+him+to+death&year_start=1750&year_end=1850&corpus=26&smoothing=10), both Brits and Americans were perfectly happy to ***stab someone dead***. But today we usually ***stab people to death*** on both sides of the pond. None of us ever used to ***beat them dead*** though.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - posh British folks used to 'cut' (ignore) people socially if they had transgressed the code in some way, and a specially severe episode would be to 'cut them dead'.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: Indeed. We can be metaphorically ***bored to death***, but even the most extreme social ostracism doesn't license metaphorically ***cutting someone to death***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers My mother sometimes used to threaten to _slap me silly_ if I didn't cease whatever misbehaviour I was carrying out, but I don't think she would have _knocked me unconscious_.

Answer (score 1):

The two sentences literally mean the same thing. But

> I crushed the cockroach dead.

is more likely to be said with pride. It emphasizes the deliberateness and the finality of the act.

> I crushed the cockroach to death.

is more likely to be said with shame or surprise. It suggests that the crushing didn't necessarily have to result in death, or that the crushing that caused the death was unintentional.

But those are just feelings based on the structure of the sentences. Literally, the two sentences mean the exact same thing.